# enable SOAP on PHP

Tags: php, soap

I would like to enable SOAP on my PHP5/Centos/Apache server.  I have full access to the server.  My php.ini file includes the below.  When I look at phpinfo(), it doesn't reference SOAP.  Any suggestions?  Thank you

```
[soap]
; Enables or disables WSDL caching feature.
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=1
; Sets the directory name where SOAP extension will put cache files.
soap.wsdl_cache_dir="/tmp"
; (time to live) Sets the number of second while cached file will be used 
; instead of original one.
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl=86400
```

EDIT - Get the following.  Tried it on two different servers.

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum install php-soap
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.ecvps.com
 * extras: mirror.spro.net
 * rpmforge: mirror.hmc.edu
 * updates: centos.mirror.facebook.net
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-soap.x86_64 0:5.1.6-34.el5_8 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-34.el5_8 for package: php-soap
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
php-soap-5.1.6-34.el5_8.x86_64 from updates has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-34.el5_8 is needed by package php-soap-5.1.6-34.el5_8.x86_64 (updates)
Error: Missing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-34.el5_8 is needed by package php-soap-5.1.6-34.el5_8.x86_64 (updates)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

SECOND EDIT PART 1

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum --enablerepo=webtatic install php-soap
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.ecvps.com
 * extras: mirrors.ecvps.com
 * rpmforge: mirror.hmc.edu
 * updates: mirror.5ninesolutions.com
adobe-linux-x86_64                                       |  951 B     00:00
base                                                     | 1.1 kB     00:00
extras                                                   | 2.1 kB     00:00
rpmforge                                                 | 1.9 kB     00:00
updates                                                  | 1.9 kB     00:00
webtatic                                                 |  951 B     00:00
webtatic/primary                                         |  40 kB     00:00
webtatic                                                                182/182
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-soap.x86_64 0:5.3.13-1.w5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.3.13-1.w5 for package: php-soap
--> Running transaction check
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.3.4-1.w5 for package: php
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.3.4-1.w5 for package: php-cli
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.3.4-1.w5 for package: php-mysql
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.3.4-1.w5 for package: php-xml
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.3.4-1.w5 for package: php-imap
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.3.4-1.w5 for package: php-odbc
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.3.4-1.w5 for package: php-xmlrpc
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.3.4-1.w5 for package: php-ldap
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.3.4-1.w5 for package: php-pdo
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.3.4-1.w5 for package: php-gd
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.3.4-1.w5 for package: php-mbstring
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.3.4-1.w5 for package: php-mcrypt
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.3.13-1.w5 set to be updated
--> Running transaction check
--> Processing Dependency: php = 5.3.4-1.w5 for package: php-devel
---> Package php.x86_64 0:5.3.13-1.w5 set to be updated
---> Package php-cli.x86_64 0:5.3.13-1.w5 set to be updated
---> Package php-gd.x86_64 0:5.3.13-1.w5 set to be updated
---> Package php-imap.x86_64 0:5.3.13-1.w5 set to be updated
---> Package php-ldap.x86_64 0:5.3.13-1.w5 set to be updated
---> Package php-mbstring.x86_64 0:5.3.13-1.w5 set to be updated
---> Package php-mcrypt.x86_64 0:5.3.13-1.w5 set to be updated
---> Package php-mysql.x86_64 0:5.3.13-1.w5 set to be updated
---> Package php-odbc.x86_64 0:5.3.13-1.w5 set to be updated
---> Package php-pdo.x86_64 0:5.3.13-1.w5 set to be updated
---> Package php-xml.x86_64 0:5.3.13-1.w5 set to be updated
---> Package php-xmlrpc.x86_64 0:5.3.13-1.w5 set to be updated
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-devel.x86_64 0:5.3.13-1.w5 set to be updated
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package              Arch           Version             Repository        Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 php-soap             x86_64         5.3.13-1.w5         webtatic         144 k
Updating for dependencies:
 php                  x86_64         5.3.13-1.w5         webtatic         1.4 M
 php-cli              x86_64         5.3.13-1.w5         webtatic         2.6 M
 php-common           x86_64         5.3.13-1.w5         webtatic         653 k
 php-devel            x86_64         5.3.13-1.w5         webtatic         622 k
 php-gd               x86_64         5.3.13-1.w5         webtatic         107 k
 php-imap             x86_64         5.3.13-1.w5         webtatic          50 k
 php-ldap             x86_64         5.3.13-1.w5         webtatic          35 k
 php-mbstring         x86_64         5.3.13-1.w5         webtatic         1.2 M
 php-mcrypt           x86_64         5.3.13-1.w5         webtatic          30 k
 php-mysql            x86_64         5.3.13-1.w5         webtatic          91 k
 php-odbc             x86_64         5.3.13-1.w5         webtatic          50 k
 php-pdo              x86_64         5.3.13-1.w5         webtatic          66 k
 php-xml              x86_64         5.3.13-1.w5         webtatic         118 k
 php-xmlrpc           x86_64         5.3.13-1.w5         webtatic          50 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install       1 Package(s)
Upgrade      14 Package(s)

Total download size: 7.1 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
(1/15): php-mcrypt-5.3.13-1.w5.x86_64.rpm                |  30 kB     00:00
(2/15): php-ldap-5.3.13-1.w5.x86_64.rpm                  |  35 kB     00:00
(3/15): php-xmlrpc-5.3.13-1.w5.x86_64.rpm                |  50 kB     00:00
(4/15): php-imap-5.3.13-1.w5.x86_64.rpm                  |  50 kB     00:00
(5/15): php-odbc-5.3.13-1.w5.x86_64.rpm                  |  50 kB     00:00
(6/15): php-pdo-5.3.13-1.w5.x86_64.rpm                   |  66 kB     00:00
(7/15): php-mysql-5.3.13-1.w5.x86_64.rpm                 |  91 kB     00:00
(8/15): php-gd-5.3.13-1.w5.x86_64.rpm                    | 107 kB     00:00
(9/15): php-xml-5.3.13-1.w5.x86_64.rpm                   | 118 kB     00:00
(10/15): php-soap-5.3.13-1.w5.x86_64.rpm                 | 144 kB     00:00
(11/15): php-devel-5.3.13-1.w5.x86_64.rpm                | 622 kB     00:00
(12/15): php-common-5.3.13-1.w5.x86_64.rpm               | 653 kB     00:01
(13/15): php-mbstring-5.3.13-1.w5.x86_64.rpm             | 1.2 MB     00:00
(14/15): php-5.3.13-1.w5.x86_64.rpm                      | 1.4 MB     00:02
(15/15): php-cli-5.3.13-1.w5.x86_64.rpm                  | 2.6 MB     00:02
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                           604 kB/s | 7.1 MB     00:12
warning: rpmts_HdrFromFdno: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID cf4c4ff9
webtatic/gpgkey                                          | 1.6 kB     00:00


Public key for php-mbstring-5.3.13-1.w5.x86_64.rpm is not installed
```

SECOND EDIT PART 2

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum --enablerepo=webtatic install  webtatic-release
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.ecvps.com
 * extras: mirrors.ecvps.com
 * rpmforge: mirror.hmc.edu
 * updates: centos.mirror.facebook.net
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package webtatic-release.noarch 0:5-2 set to be updated
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package                   Arch            Version      Repository         Size
================================================================================
Updating:
 webtatic-release          noarch          5-2          webtatic           11 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install       0 Package(s)
Upgrade       1 Package(s)

Total download size: 11 k
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
webtatic-release-5-2.noarch.rpm                          |  11 kB     00:00
warning: rpmts_HdrFromFdno: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID cf4c4ff9
webtatic/gpgkey                                          | 1.6 kB     00:00


Public key for webtatic-release-5-2.noarch.rpm is not installed
```

Comment: Have you installed php-soap? Run 'yum install php-soap' to do it

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You may need to make sure the PHP SOAP package is installed. Try running `yum install php-soap` as root.

**Edit:** Adapted from this [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350101/php-mysql-connect-failing-with-no-error-message) to a similar question:

run this:

```
yum --enablerepo=webtatic install php-soap
```

this tells yum to get the packages from webtatic repository (in addition to system configured repositories). If you want webtatic among system enabled repositories, run:

```
rpm --import http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/RPM-GPG-KEY-webtatic-andy
yum --enablerepo=webtatic install  webtatic-release
```

Comment: Tried but got... Missing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-34.el5_8 is needed by package php-soap-5.1.6-34.el5_8.x86_64 (updates)

Comment: looks like there is a mismatch between the version of PHP on your server and the one in yum. This could be due to mixed repos - maybe try a `yum list available | grep soap` to see if there are differing php-soap versions available.

Comment: Gave me the following:
php-soap.x86_64       5.1.6-34.el5_8        updates
php53-soap.x86_64  5.3.3-7.el5_8          updates
python-soap.noarch  0.11.6-1.el5.rf        rpmforge
soapbox.x86_64         0.3.1-1.2.el5.rf       rpmforge

Comment: php-mcrypt-5.3.4-1.w5
php-mysql-5.3.4-1.w5
php-common-5.3.4-1.w5
php-xml-5.3.4-1.w5
php-5.3.4-1.w5
php-ldap-5.3.4-1.w5
php-devel-5.3.4-1.w5
phpmyadmin-2.11.11.3-2.el5.rf
php-pear-1.4.9-8.el5
php-cli-5.3.4-1.w5
php-imap-5.3.4-1.w5
php-odbc-5.3.4-1.w5
php-pdo-5.3.4-1.w5
php-xmlrpc-5.3.4-1.w5
php-mbstring-5.3.4-1.w5
php-gd-5.3.4-1.w5

Comment: haha, you're close enough you could probably google your way now
`rpm --import http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/RPM-GPG-KEY-webtatic-andy`

Comment: After yum --enablerepo=webtatic install php-soap, I keep getting "Error getting repository data for webtatic, repository not found". 

Any idea?

Comment: @MattP See [this page](https://webtatic.com/projects/yum-repository/) for instructions to install the webtatic repository

Comment: after run this command `find -name soap.so` in root folder i see this is soap path `./usr/lib64/php/modules/soap.so` i set this line  `extension='./usr/lib64/php/modules/soap.so'` `/etc/php.ini` file and restart httpd services in cent os 6. but still it couldn't enable soap service. any idea?

Answer (score 1):

In case that you have Ubuntu in your machine try  the following in your terminal:

1. sudo apt-get install php-soap
2. service apache2 restart

To check use php test file inside it only the following function `phpinfo();` 
and check results in the browser which contains the following module like that image:
[image]