# Enable SOAP on Plesk

Tags: php, soap, plesk

This question has been asked before but none of the solutions work for me. I was mainly following this one - [enable SOAP on PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11014431/enable-soap-on-php) to no avail.  I have a php script which is giving the following error:

```
Error message: Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found in /var/www/pathtofile/file.php on line 90
```

I guess need to install soap on a Plesk 11.0.9 and CentOS 5.6 (Final).  This is what I have by default in the php.ini file:

```
[soap]
; Enables or disables WSDL caching feature.
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=1
; Sets the directory name where SOAP extension will put cache files.
soap.wsdl_cache_dir="/tmp"
; (time to live) Sets the number of second while cached file will be used
; instead of original one.
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl=86400
```

and **php -i | grep soap** gives me:

```
'--enable-soap=shared'
```

if I run **yum install php-soap** I get the following:

```
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-soap.i386 0:5.1.6-32.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-32.el5 for package: php-soap
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-common.i386 0:5.1.6-32.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Conflict: php53-common conflicts php-common
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
php53-common-5.3.3-13.el5_8.i386 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> php53-common conflicts with php-common
Error: php53-common conflicts with php-common
```

if I run **yum install php53-soap** I get the following:

```
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php53-soap.i386 0:5.3.3-5.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php53-common = 5.3.3-5.el5 for package: php53-soap
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
php53-soap-5.3.3-5.el5.i386 from base has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: php53-common = 5.3.3-5.el5 is needed by package php53-soap-5.3.3-5.el5.i386 (base)
Error: Missing Dependency: php53-common = 5.3.3-5.el5 is needed by package php53-soap-    5.3.3-5.el5.i386 (base)
```

If I run **yum list available | grep soap** I get:

```
php-soap.i386                            5.1.6-32.el5                     base
php53-soap.i386                          5.3.3-5.el5                      base
```

if I run **yum list available | grep soap** I get the following:

```
php53-common-5.3.3-13.el5_8
php53-mysql-5.3.3-13.el5_8
php53-xml-5.3.3-13.el5_8
psa-php53-configurator-1.6.2-cos5.build110120608.16
php5-ioncube-loader-4.0.14-12042719
php53-5.3.3-13.el5_8
php53-mbstring-5.3.3-13.el5_8
php-pear-1.4.9-8.el5
psa11-php-fakepackage-11.0.9-cos5.build110120608.16
php53-pdo-5.3.3-13.el5_8
php53-imap-5.3.3-13.el5_8
php53-sqlite2-5.3.2-11070811
php53-cli-5.3.3-13.el5_8
php53-gd-5.3.3-13.el5_8
php53-devel-5.3.3-13.el5_8
```

If I run **yum list | grep php** I get:

```
php-pear.noarch                         1:1.4.9-8.el5                  installed
php5-ioncube-loader.i386                4.0.14-12042719                installed
php53.i386                              5.3.3-13.el5_8                 installed
php53-cli.i386                          5.3.3-13.el5_8                 installed
php53-common.i386                       5.3.3-13.el5_8                 installed
php53-devel.i386                        5.3.3-13.el5_8                 installed
php53-gd.i386                           5.3.3-13.el5_8                 installed
php53-imap.i386                         5.3.3-13.el5_8                 installed
php53-mbstring.i386                     5.3.3-13.el5_8                 installed
php53-mysql.i386                        5.3.3-13.el5_8                 installed
php53-pdo.i386                          5.3.3-13.el5_8                 installed
php53-sqlite2.i386                      5.3.2-11070811                 installed    
php53-xml.i386                          5.3.3-13.el5_8                 installed
psa-php53-configurator.i386             1.6.2-cos5.build110120608.16   installed
psa11-php-fakepackage.i386              11.0.9-cos5.build110120608.16  installed
graphviz-php.i386                       2.12-8.el5.centos              extras
php.i386                                5.1.6-32.el5                   base
php-bcmath.i386                         5.1.6-32.el5                   base
php-cli.i386                            5.1.6-32.el5                   base
php-common.i386                         5.1.6-32.el5                   base
php-dba.i386                            5.1.6-32.el5                   base
php-dbase.i386                          5.1.6-15.el5.centos.1          extras
php-devel.i386                          5.1.6-32.el5                   base
php-gd.i386                             5.1.6-32.el5                   base
php-imap.i386                           5.1.6-32.el5                   base
php-ldap.i386                           5.1.6-32.el5                   base
php-mbstring.i386                       5.1.6-32.el5                   base
php-mcrypt.i386                         5.1.6-15.el5.centos.1          extras
php-mhash.i386                          5.1.6-15.el5.centos.1          extras
php-mssql.i386                          5.1.6-15.el5.centos.1          extras
php-mysql.i386                          5.1.6-32.el5                   base
php-ncurses.i386                        5.1.6-32.el5                   base
php-odbc.i386                           5.1.6-32.el5                   base
php-pdo.i386                            5.1.6-32.el5                   base
php-pear-Auth-SASL.noarch               1.0.2-4.el5.centos             extras
php-pear-DB.noarch                      1.7.13-1.el5.centos            extras
php-pear-Date.noarch                    1.4.7-2.el5.centos             extras
php-pear-File.noarch                    1.2.2-1.el5.centos             extras
php-pear-HTTP-Request.noarch            1.4.2-1.el5.centos             extras
php-pear-Log.noarch                     1.9.13-1.el5.centos            extras
php-pear-MDB2.noarch                    2.4.1-2.el5.centos             extras
php-pear-MDB2-Driver-mysql.noarch       1.4.1-3.el5.centos             extras
php-pear-Mail.noarch                    1.1.14-1.el5.centos            extras
php-pear-Mail-Mime.noarch               1.4.0-1.el5.centos             extras
php-pear-Net-SMTP.noarch                1.2.10-1.el5.centos            extras
php-pear-Net-Sieve.noarch               1.1.5-2.el5.centos             extras
php-pear-Net-Socket.noarch              1.0.8-1.el5.centos             extras
php-pear-Net-URL.noarch                 1.0.15-1.el5.centos            extras
php-pecl-Fileinfo.i386                  1.0.4-3.el5.centos             extras
php-pecl-memcache.i386                  2.2.3-1.el5_2                  extras
php-pgsql.i386                          5.1.6-32.el5                   base
php-readline.i386                       5.1.6-15.el5.centos.1          extras
php-snmp.i386                           5.1.6-32.el5                   base
php-soap.i386                           5.1.6-32.el5                   base
php-tidy.i386                           5.1.6-15.el5.centos.1          extras
php-xml.i386                            5.1.6-32.el5                   base
php-xmlrpc.i386                         5.1.6-32.el5                   base
php53-bcmath.i386                       5.3.3-5.el5                    base
php53-dba.i386                          5.3.3-5.el5                    base
php53-intl.i386                         5.3.3-5.el5                    base
php53-ldap.i386                         5.3.3-5.el5                    base
php53-odbc.i386                         5.3.3-5.el5                    base
php53-pgsql.i386                        5.3.3-5.el5                    base
php53-process.i386                      5.3.3-5.el5                    base
php53-pspell.i386                       5.3.3-5.el5                    base
php53-snmp.i386                         5.3.3-5.el5                    base
php53-soap.i386                         5.3.3-5.el5                    base
php53-xmlrpc.i386                       5.3.3-5.el5                    base
```

Any ideas on how to fix this problem with soap please?

Comment: Which PHP-version do you have installed? Seems to me that you mixed PHP 5.3 and PHP < 5.3.

Comment: according to plesk it is **5.3.3-13.el5_8**

Comment: "No package php35-soap available." You accidentally switched the 3 and the 5. You sure that isn't the problem and you've executed yum with the right package?

Comment: Thanks for that typo - I am tired already this morning :) Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php53-soap.i386 0:5.3.3-5.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php53-common = 5.3.3-5.el5 for package: php53-soap
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
php53-soap-5.3.3-5.el5.i386 from base has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: php53-common = 5.3.3-5.el5 is needed by package php53-soap-5.3.3-5.el5.i386 (base)
Error: Missing Dependency: php53-common = 5.3.3-5.el5 is needed by package php53-soap-5.3.3-5.el5.i386 (base)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root problem is that, for some reason, the repos you're talking to have version 5.3.3-**5**.el5 of the SOAP extension, but you have a newer version of the rest of PHP, version 5.3.3-**13**.el5_8.

That makes little sense, as -13.el5_8 is the current version I see in the official CentOS repos for all PHP modules, including SOAP.

You probably want to `sudo yum clean all` and make sure your repo list is up to date and using the correct sources.  If not for the fact that you're running a control panel suite, I'd also recommend a plain old `sudo yum update`, but I'm not sure if Plesk will enjoy that.

If it turns out that you're actually using Plesk-approved repos, you'll need to tell *them* to get their act in gear.

Comment: This is the response from the service provider (godaddy) - You may need to add addition repositories to retrieve that specific version, however this is not something we would be able to assist with. This page has more information on that - http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories.  Shall I try using **sudo yum clean all** - this is a live environment - will it effect the users?

Comment: No, cleaning up the various cached bits should not impact users.

Comment: Thanks @Charles Do I need to do some else after running **sudo yum clean all**? Do I need to install/yum something?

Comment: No, the cache cleaning should be it.  After cleaning up, you *might* be able to run the install command again.  Yum will reach out to the repo servers and ask them for their packages.  If you get the same errors, then your next step is going to figuring out why the repos you're using are feeding you outdated packages.

Comment: I ran the command and then tried the install command again. Same Error: `php53-soap-5.3.3-5.el5.i386 from base has depsolving problems`

Comment: I noticed that this repository has the package I need - http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/updates/i386/RPMS/php53-soap-5.3.3-13.el5_8.i386.rpm.  Can I use this command - **rpm -Uhv http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/updates/i386/RPMS/php53-soap-5.3.3-13.el5_8.i386.rpm**?

Comment: I was about to recommend that, with a big fat caveat.  I'm gonna put it in bold.  **Your repo config is broken and you may be running outdated software with known security holes.**  I'm going to *highly* recommend getting this fixed.  If your hosting provider won't help you, you might try asking over on Super User or over on Unix.  The links are in the footer below.  The main problem, so you can ask for accurate help, is that you're getting mirrors that are horribly out of date, and something in the configuration files in `/etc/yum.repos.d` is out of date.  The actual fix is out of scope on SO

Comment: (I'd actually recommend `wget`ting the RPM file, then doing `yum install ./whatever.rpm` instead of using the `rpm` tool directly.  This way, `yum`'ll complain if there are any more missing bits and pieces.)

Comment: **Fantastic - that worked!!!!!** Thanks for your help! On a side note these are my repos (from godaddy) -  `*addons: n1plmirror02.shr.prod.ams1.secureserver.net
 * base: n1plmirror02.shr.prod.ams1.secureserver.net
 * extras: n1plmirror02.shr.prod.ams1.secureserver.net
 * update: n1plmirror02.shr.prod.ams1.secureserver.net`

Comment: Yeah, it's totally their problem then.  Poke their support reps one more time and let them know their repos are out of date.  If they won't fix it, find a better company to give your money to.