# install SOAP Extension in apache from Remote System

Tags: php, linux, apache, soap

I was trying to use soap services but i have been facing following error

```
Fatal error: Class "SoapClient" not found
```

I have determined one part that was the easy one that soap extension is not installed. So now i want to install it but i can only access to the server through terminal and root user.
I cannot find any tutorial which can guide me to install soap extension to remote server. Also I am not sure what risks are involved as i am very beginner to it. So any kind of help will be much appreciated. 
my php version is 5.1.6, apache version is 2.2.3 and Server OS is CentOS release 5.2

Regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [enable SOAP on PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11014431/enable-soap-on-php)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.wallpaperama.com/forums/how-to-install-php-soap-extension-in-apache-linux-php-server-remove-t1756.html

The above url shows you how to install soap extension for php and [Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391442/fatal-error-class-soapclient-not-found) this link would show you do you have it installed or not or it is enabled or not.

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker