# Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found in [...]

Tags: php

I'm getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found in [...]
```

I know that I need to uncomment the `extension=php_soap.dll`  in `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`  and I did.

But I still get the error and I dont know why. I also restarted the Apache after chaning the php.ini.

Also in my php_info() I cant find any `soap` string. What can be wrong here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11014431/enable-soap-on-php

Comment: You shoudl _always_ take a look at the http servers log files in such case. This is where typically php writes its errors and warnings. It certainly has told you something whilst apache has been restarted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just needed to install the php-soap extension with my package manager. Now its working fine